# Geopandas World and Country Maps Libraries

Tags: python, geopandas, world-map

How can i get different world map views besides the default 'naturalearth_lowres'. For info, I'am able to access that using the following code:

```
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
```

I find this version (naturalearth lowres) to be very dull and would like to see if there are other options ( such as one that shows world map from satellite view), also, map should have high resolution as i need to import many data points across the globe.

Satellite view example:

[image]

Appreciate your help.

Comment: I think the first example in the geopandas documentation gallery covers this

Comment: The example mentioned by Paul is this one: https://geopandas.org/gallery/plotting_basemap_background.html Although I don't think it completely covers this question (that's why it is a comment)